# How to set up a custom property without displaying it on browser?

Tags: razor

I created an int typed propety on a cshtml view to use as a counter, and when i set a value on it, it is beeing displayed on my webform. How do I prevent this?

> Blockquote CODE
>   [PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eS6j.png)

int countResposta = 0;

@foreach (var questao in questionarioDTO.Questoes.OrderBy(s => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList())
{
   
                            
                                
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                                
                                                    
                                                    
                                                        
                                                            **@count) @questao.Descricao**

@* WHEN I SET THE VALUE HERE IT'S BEEING DISPLAYED ON BROWSER *@
@(countResposta = 0)

@foreach (var resposta in questao.Respostas.OrderBy(s => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList())
                                                            {
                                                                **@(alfa[countResposta]).**@Html.RadioButton(questao.IdQuestao.ToString(), resposta.IdResposta.ToString(), new { @id = resposta.IdResposta.ToString() })@resposta.Descricao
                                                                countResposta++;
                                                            }
                                                        
                                                        
                                                            @*style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 310px; border: none">*@
                                                            
                                                                @if (count > 1)
                                                                {
                                                                    Anterior
                                                                }

```
                                                            @if (MaxRegistros > count)
                                                            {
                                                                <a href="#etapa@(count + 1)" id="linkEtapa@(count + 1)" onclick="$(document).scrollTop(0);" aria-controls="etapa@(count + 1)" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-success ripple"><span class="ink animate" style="height: 134px; width: 134px; top: -45px; left: 31.5781px;"></span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw"></i>Próxima</a>
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                <a id="aSalvar" class="btn btn-primary btn-success-geg" onclick="javascript: SalvarForm();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>&nbsp;<strong>Finalizar</strong></a>
                                                            }

                                                            @*<a id="aSalvar" class="btn btn-primary btn-success-geg" onclick="javascript: SalvarForm('@ViewBag.CodigoEmpregadoPesquisa');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>&nbsp;<strong>Finalizar</strong></a>*@
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    count++;
                }
```

> REsult [resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Uhq.png)

Answer (score 0):

need to use lke this:
@{ countResposta = 0; } @* need to set spaces before and after {, } *@

rather than:

@(countResposta = 0)